# How to insert data into Managed Metadata field of any Document Set using PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, managed-metadata, managed-metadata-service

I am creating a Document Set for a library using powershell and that document set contains some mandatory managed metadata fields. I am able to create document set but how can I insert data into those managed metadata fields at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

You have to connect to the term store and then construct a TaxonomyFieldValue and then use the target field's SetFieldValue() method to assign the value.

See here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepointadminprevious/thread/4c63fff1-8681-42a1-9fd2-256f1f80935b

regards,
KS

Comment: The link which you have provided is applicable for List managed metadata column. But, I have to add value into Document Set managed metadata column. Still not able to figure out...

Comment: Just for information -- the column in which i have to insert data is a site column which added into the Document Set content type.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone.

You have to get a reference to the Managed metadata item from term store as shown below

```
$someTerm = $term.Terms | where-object {$_.Name -eq "SomeTerm" }
```

Create the document set as shown below

```
[Hashtable]$docSetProperties = @{}
$newDocumentSet=Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($list.RootFolder,"TestDocSet",$DocContentType.Id, $docSetProperties )
```

Get a reference to the inserted document set

```
$id = $newDocumentSet.Item.ID
$spItem = $list.GetItemById($id)
```

Get a reference to the taxonomy field from the inserted document set

```
$taxMMField = $spItem.Fields['YourManagedMetaDataField'] -as   [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]
$taxMMField.SetFieldValue($spItem, $someTerm)
```

Call the Update method on the item

```
$spItem.Update()
```

This will update the Managed metadata field in the Document Set.

Answer (score 0):

Complete sample

```
$webUrl = "http://portaladdress.local"
$inputDir = "C:\sampledata"

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $webUrl 
$spsite = $spWeb.Site

$docLibrary = $spWeb.Lists["DocumentLibraryListName"]
$spFolder = $spWeb.GetFolder($docLibrary.rootFolder.URL + "/")

$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $spsite
$taxonomyField = $docLibrary.Fields["TaxononomyFieldName"]
$termStoreID = $taxonomyField.SspId 
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores[$termStoreID]  
$termsetID = $taxonomyField.TermSetId   
$termset = $termStore.GetTermSet($termsetID)

#################

### Get Document Set Content Type from list   
$cType = $docLibrary.ContentTypes["DocumentSetContentTypeName"]   

### Create Document Set Properties Hashtable   
[Hashtable]$docsetProperties = @{"DescriptionFieldName"="some text"}   
$docsetProperties = @{"DatefiledName"="06/06/2006"} 

### Create new Document Set   
$newDocumentSet = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::Create($spFolder,"documentset title",$cType.Id,$docsetProperties)   

$term = $termset.GetTerms( "TermLabel", $true)
$id = $newDocumentSet.Item.ID;
$spItem = $docLibrary.GetItemById($id);
#this is a critical point: get  a reference to the field by the item instead of using that from the list we got before (ie: $taxonomyField)
$taxMMField = $spItem.Fields['TaxononomyFieldName'] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField];
$taxMMField.SetFieldValue($spItem, $term);
$spItem.Update();

#upload a file into the document set
$FilePath = "$inputDir\FileToBeLoadIntoTheDocumentset.pdf"
$FileName = "FileToBeLoadIntoTheDocumentset.pdf"
$file= Get-Item $FilePath
$spFile = $newDocumentSet.Folder.Files.Add($newDocumentSet.Folder.Url + "/" + $FileName,$file.OpenRead(),$false)
$spFileItem = $spFile.Item 
$spFileItem["Titolo"] = "File title";
$spFileItem.Update()
$spFileItem.File.CheckIn("checkin comments", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)

$spWeb.Dispose()
```